# .Net calling C++ intermittently working in Windows 10

Tags: c++, .net, windows, interop

We have C++ DLLs compiled with 2010 being called by an application in CSharp .net 4.0. The C++ output three IntPtr(s) which are then converted to Bitmap(s) using Bitmap.FromHbitmap. Everything was working fine in Windows 7. We have upgraded to Windows 10. Now, intermittently, an SEH exception is caught in the CSharp code.
Has anyone experienced a similar problem or have any suggestions?
Let me know if you would like code posted.
Thank you

Comment: I can suggest finding the problem and fixing it...

Comment: Posting your entire code will not be useful. stackoverflow.com is not a free code debugging service.

Comment: Any leads in the SEH?

Comment: It is a SEH 0x80004005 External component has thrown an exception. There is no inner exception or specifics.

Comment: If the C++ DLLs were compiled with /MD or /MDd, you must install the Visual Studio 2010 C++ runtime. But you should get a message box when that happens. Otherwise, try running the app elevated and see if there's a security issue.

Comment: I tried both, neither helped. It is interesting that it works sometimes, as opposed to never.

Answer (score 0):

Try with recompiling the C++ DLL on Windows 10 environment and try again.

Comment: I will see if I can do this. The guy who wrote the original code is gone and I need to try to find it.

Comment: I am currently unable to recompile due to dependencies on older Intel libraries.

Comment: I asked management for some C++ personal and am getting him all setup today. We will attempt to build on a Windows 10 computer with VS2010 as debug to get PDBs from there. I will let you guys know how things go. Will probably be a few days though.

Comment: I found a more recent version of the code on a former co-workers computer. I built on Windows 10 using VS2010 SP1 and ran the C++ dll on the same computer. No joy. We are attempting to debug the code now.

Answer (score 0):

My coworker was able to identify the problem. It was an issue with the pointer within C++ code. Here are his comments: ImageToResize needs to be a reference as it is reassigned here.  The only reason this code functioned previously appears to be due to the fact that cvReleaseImage() followed by cvCreateImage() happened to reuse the same memory (most of the time) so nothing 'moved'.
The parameter was changed from: *ImageToResize to *&ImageToResize.
So, this maybe was a sign of different memory allocation styles between Windows 7 and Windows 10.
I hope this helps someone in the future.